# Time tracking with planning

Tags: time-management, productivity, task-management, planning

I am looking for a time tracker/task manager with planning functionality, ideally as follows:

- I can create any task and specify **how long I want to spend on it**, the task can be repeated (eg. every day 1 hour, every monday and friday 2 hours etc.) - this is the core functionality
- I have some simple summary of daily tasks / daily ToDos
- I can track if I have completed the task (either automatically with the time tracker or just tick some box)

I dont need to specify at what time to start working on that task or anything, just the duration.

Web app (paid/unpaid/open source) would be the best.

Comment: There's a comprehensive list for you to consider [here](https://www.capterra.com/time-tracking-software/) based on your specific needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I am using [Focus To-Do](https://www.focustodo.cn/) app, that has everything I need. Just in case anyone needed the same. :)

Answer (score 0):

We have recently developed a new project management tool with full time tracking functionality - [Teamhood](https://teamhood.com). You can create recurring tasks and set the time you want to spend on them. As well as being able to take note of the actual time spent by entering it manually or tracking live as you work.

The Dashboard view will show the items due, so you will know what has to be done each day and once a task is completed you can mark it done to know what is going on.

Learn more about Teamhood [here](http://teamhood.com/features/).